# Is it possible to connect to an old Kafka version (like 0.11) using new versions of spring-kafka like v2.5.4.RELEASE?

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-kafka-test

I constructed a spring boot application to produce data in a Kafka, but now I need to connect this application to an old Kafka (0.11v). I tried just changing the bootstrap-server, but I receive connection errors.

I doubled checked if this Kafka instance is working, and other applications are connecting.

My question is if a new version of spring-Kafka like v2.5.4.RELEASE can connect to an old version of Kafka. Is there any configuration I can add to use legacy Kafka instances? I constructed a spring boot application to produce data in a Kafka, but now I need to connect this application to an old Kafka (0.11v). I tried just changing the bootstrap-server, but I receive connection errors.

I doubled checked if this Kafka instance is working, and other applications are connecting.

My question is if a new version of spring-Kafka like v2.5.4.RELEASE can connect to an old version of Kafka. Is there any configuration I can add to use legacy Kafka instances?

Answer (score 0):

In general, yes, as long as you don't use features provided by the newer brokers.

Backwards compatibility for the Java clients has been pretty good since 0.10.2.x.

There is a compatibility matrix [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Compatibility+Matrix) but it hasn't been updated since the 1.0.0 clients.

SK v2.5.4 uses the 2.5.0 clients (2.5.5 uses 2.5.1). I haven't tried connecting to such an old broker lately, what is the nature of the connection errors?

**EDIT**

I just ran a Boot app using Spring Kafka 2.5.5 against an 0.11.0.3 broker with no problems.

Comment: I just ran a Boot app using Spring Kafka 2.5.5 against an 0.11.0.3 broker with no problems.